# Convert query SQL Server to @Query Spring JPA

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

I am not able to convert.

If shoppingList_ID is null, have value euro, If shoppingLis_ID is not null, i need search value euro on table.

Table Products

| ID | ShoppingList_ID | Product | Value_Euro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | A | 2 |
| 2 | NULL | B | 4 |
| 3 | NULL | C | 5 |
| 4 | NULL | D | 6 |
| 5 | 1 | A | **?** |
| 6 | 1 | B | **?** |
| 7 | 2 | A | **?** |
| 8 | 2 | C | **?** |

ID 5: Value is 2
ID 6: Value is 4
ID 7: Value is 2
ID 8: Value is 5

Output:

| ID | ShoppingList_ID | Product | Value_Euro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | A | **2** |
| 8 | 2 | C | **5** |

Solution SQL:

```
select p.id, p.shopping_id, p.product, p_value.value_euro from (select * from products) as p
left join (select product, value_euro from products where value_euro is not null)  as p_value
on p.product = p_value.product 
Where shopping_id = 2 --extra condition
```

Bad solution Spring JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT p from Products p LEFT JOIN p.Products pv Where p.shopping_id = 2 and pv.value_euro is not null ")
public List<Product> getShoppingListValue();
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing sample data, the expected output, an explanation of the query's logic.

Comment: Ok, changed my question :)